# Linearly interpolate from one speed to the other based on percentage

Tags: c

I am trying to slowly decelerate based on a percentage.

Basically: if percentage is 0 the speed should be `speed_max`, if the percentage hits 85 the speed should be `speed_min`, continuing with `speed_min` until the percentage hits 100%. At percentages between 0% and 85%, the speed should be calculated with the percentage.

I started writing the code already, though I am not sure how to continue:

```
// Target 
int degrees = 90;

// Making sure we're at 0
resetGyro(0);

int speed_max = 450;
int speed_min = 150;

float currentDeg = 0;
float percentage = 0;

while(percentage < 100)
{   
    //??
    getGyroDeg(&currentDeg);
    percentage = (degrees/100)*currentDeg;
}
killMotors(1);
```

Someone in the comments asked why I am doing this.

Unfortunately, I am working with very limited hardware and a pretty bad gyroscope, all while trying to guarantee +- 1 degree precision.

To do this, I am starting at `speed_max`, slowly decreasing to `speed_min` (this is to have better control over the motors) when nearing the target value (90).

Why does it stop decelerating at 85%? This is to really be precise and hit the target value successfully.

Comment: You say 'lerp from one speed'; unfortunately, 'lerp' is not a verb in English, so it is not clear what you're asking from the title.  Did you mean 'leap'?

Comment: It's short for linear interpolation.

Comment: Oh…well, it might be a good idea to say that in the question; it's not a term I've come across (but I don't work with gyroscopes under computer control).  I see that Wikipedia does mention 'lerp' under its article on [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Comment: I don’t understand ‘if the perentage is 0 the speed should be speed_max’ - this doesn’t make sense

Comment: @barny: The `percentage` value is the amount of slowing from maximum speed, with 85 being the number at which you hit minimum speed.

Comment: Using “power” (i.e. something the code can control) instead of “speed” (something the code can only measure) makes more sense to me.

Comment: If you want to use `int`, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm uses all `int`s to interpolate, giving the exact answers. It may be of interest especially if you're working on limited hardware, (without FPU?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear interpolation is fairly straight forward.

- At `percentage` 0, the speed should be `speed_max`.
- At `percentage` 85, the speed should be `speed_min`.
- At `percentage` values greater than 85, the speed should still be `speed_min`.
- Between 0 and 85, the speed should be linearly interpolated between `speed_max` and `speed_min`, so `percentage` is a 'amount of drop from maximum speed'.

Assuming `percentage` is of type `float`:

```
float speed_from_percentage(float percent)
{
    if (percent <= 0.0)
        return speed_max;
    if (percent >= 85.0)
        return speed_min;
    return speed_min + (speed_max - speed_min) * (85.0 - percentage) / 85.0;
}
```

You can also replace the final return with the equivalent:

```
return speed_max - (speed_max - speed_min) * percentage / 85.0;
```

If you're truly pedantic, all the constants should be suffixed with `F` to indicate `float` and hence use `float` arithmetic instead of `double` arithmetic.  And hence you should probably also use `float` for `speed_min` and `speed_max`.  If everything is meant to be integer arithmetic, you can change `float` to `int` and drop the `.0` from the expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming speed is linearly calculated based on percentages from 0 to 85 (and stays at speed_min with percentage is gt 85), then this is your formula for calculating speed:

```
if (percentage >= 85)
{
    speed = speed_min;
}
else
{
     speed = speed_max - (((speed_max - speed_min)*percentage)/85);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `getGyroDeg` is input from the controller, what you are describing is a proportional control. A constant response curve, *ie*, 0 to 85 has an output of 450 to 150, and 150 after that, is an *ad-hoc* approach, based on experience. However, a properly initialised [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) generally attains a faster time to set-point and greater stability.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static float sim_current = 0.0f;
static float sim_dt = 0.01f;
static float sim_speed = 0.0f /* 150.0f */;

static void getGyroDeg(float *const current) {
    assert(current);
    sim_current += sim_speed * sim_dt;
    /* Simulate measurement error. */
    *current = sim_current + 3.0 * ((2.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX) - 1.0);
}

static void setGyroSpeed(const float speed) {
    assert(speed >= /*150.0f*/-450.0f && speed <= 450.0f);
    sim_speed = speed;
}

int main(void) {
    /* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller
     u(t) = K_p e(t) + K_i \int_0^t e(\theta)d\theta + K_d de(t)/dt */
    const float setpoint = 90.0f;
    const float max = 450.0f;
    const float min = -450.0f/* 150.0f */;
    /* Random value; actually get this number. */
    const float dt = 1.0f;
    /* Tune these. */
    const float kp = 30.0f, ki = 4.0f, kd = 2.0f;

    float current, last = 0.0f, integral = 0.0f;
    float t = 0.0f;
    float e, p, i, d, pid;

    size_t count;

    for(count = 0; count < 40; count++) {
        getGyroDeg(&current);
        e = setpoint - current;

        p = kp * e;
        i = ki * integral * dt;
        d = kd * (e - last) / dt;

        last = e;

        pid = p + i + d;
        if(pid > max) {
            pid = max;
        } else if(pid < min) {
            pid = min;
        } else {
            integral += e;
        }
        setGyroSpeed(pid);
        printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", t, sim_current, pid);
        t += dt;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here, instead of the speed linearly decreasing, it calculates the speed in a control loop. However, if the minimum is 150, then it's not going to achieve greater stability; if you go over 90, then you have no way of getting back.

[image: PID controller with min 150, max 450.]

If the controls are `[-450, 450]`, it goes through zero and it is much nicer; I think this might be what you are looking for. It actively corrects for errors.

[image: PID controller with min -450, max 450.]